# Why use this awkward way to round a float to an integer?

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

In [How does DoubleUtil.DoubleToInt(double val) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102656/how-does-doubleutil-doubletointdouble-val-work) we learn that the .NET Framework has a special way of rounding floating point values:

```
public static int DoubleToInt(double val)
{
    return (0 < val) ? (int)(val + 0.5) : (int)(val - 0.5);
}
```

Why are they not just using `(int)Math.Round(val)`?

Or: Why is `Math.Round` not defined this way if this is superior? There must be some trade-off.

Comment: Because `Math.Round` has overloads for handling how many decimal places to round to and different types, would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see this being an optimization since to get the same behavior from `Round` you need to use the `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` option. From the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,f0afe85387e48317,references) this is implemented via:

```
private static unsafe double InternalRound(double value, int digits, MidpointRounding mode) {
    if (Abs(value) < doubleRoundLimit) {
        Double power10 = roundPower10Double[digits];
        value *= power10;
        if (mode == MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) {                
            double fraction = SplitFractionDouble(&value); 
            if (Abs(fraction) >= 0.5d) {
                value += Sign(fraction);
            }
        }
        else {
            // On X86 this can be inlined to just a few instructions
            value = Round(value);
        }
        value /= power10;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I can only guess that the author of the utility method did some performance comparison.

Comment: I just benchmarked variations: Round(double) is 140 units (but uses bankers rounding which nobody expects), Round(double, ToEven) is 310 units, DoubleToInt is 42 units and (int) truncation is 9 units. The benchmark included adding the result to an accumulator to make sure the result is consumed. So it's much faster (but incorrect).

Answer (score 4):

`Math.Round` would result in the creation of a `double` with the exact value needed, which would then need to be converted to an `int`.  The code here avoids the creation of that `double`.  It also allows for the elision of error handling, and the code related to other types of rounding modes or digits to round to.

Comment: This would also create an intermediate double (being `val + 0.5` or `val - 0.5`

Comment: @SimonByrne The difference being that it's much easier to perform the addition of a constant value than to do the computation to figure out what the nearest whole number is.  It's not the creating of the `double` value, it's the computation to figure out what that double value is.

Comment: Hm, should the hardware not support both truncation and rounding? I don't see why there would be a cost difference for the pure calculation. Maybe it's about cost induced by validation and detecting the digits to round to.

Comment: @usr The hardware may or may not support it.  The `Round` method attempts to use native support, if available, but does the more complex calculation if it's not available.

Answer (score 3):

They have different behaviour at value with a fractional part 1/2. According to [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned.

So if `val == 0.5`, then `Math.Round(val) == 0.0`, whereas this `DoubleToInt` would give `(int)(0.5+0.5) == 1`. In other words, `DoubleToInt` round 1/2 away from zero (like the standard C `round` function).

There is also potential here for less desirable behaviour: if `val` is actually the `double` *before* 0.5 (i.e. 0.49999999999999994) then, depending on how C# handles intermediate precision, it may in fact give 1 (as `val + 0.5` isn't representable by a `double`, and could be rounded to 1). This was in fact [an infamous specification bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9903075/392585) in Java 6 (and earlier).

Comment: Note you could get the same behavior via an overload using the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero option.